# WebApi Syntax Anomaly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

The following code compiles, though I didn't try running it yet. Why is the space being accepted ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace App.REST
{
    // Note: For instructions on enabling IIS6 or IIS7 classic mode, 
    // visit http://go.microsoft.com/?LinkId=9394801

    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig. TypeNameHandling(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're taking about the line...

```
WebApiConfig. TypeNameHandling(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

According to the language spec white space is irrelevant for syntatic grammar of a C# program.

> Five basic elements make up the lexical structure of a C# source file: Line terminators (§2.3.1), white space (§2.3.3), comments (§2.3.2), tokens (§2.4), and pre-processing directives (§2.5). **Of these basic elements, only tokens are significant in the syntactic grammar of a C# program (§2.2.3)**.

(from C# language specification chapter 2.3, emphasized by me)

Comment: Must've been a blast writting the c# syntatic analyzer, putting chomp's everwhere (I think that is what the front-end parser is called).